# How to run a command from a batch file and immediately return?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tortoisegit

When I am on the command line and do this:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe" /command:log
```

a GUI dialog of [TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) is opened and cmd.exe immediately returns, meaning that I can immediately run other commands like `dir` etc.

Because the aforementioned command is quite long, I created a helper batch file, tgit.cmd, that contains just this:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe" /command:%1 %*
```

I can now call just **tgit log** which is great, however, there is one difference: the command-line is blocked until I close the TortoiseGit dialog.

I have also tried

```
cmd /C "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe" /command:%1 %*
```

but that doesn't make any difference. How to immediately return from the batch file?

Comment: I don't think `start` is what I'm looking for - it returns an error, see below, and its task is to start a program in a new console window, which is not my intention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer from Oscar is almost correct, but needs a correction

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe" /command:%1 %*
```

Why?

`start` command has a curious behaviour: the first quoted argument is used to determine the title of a new `cmd` window, and no, it doesn't matter that no `cmd` window will be started. First quoted argument is the title.

That is the reason for the empty double quotes in the previous code. Without it, what the `start` command sees is

```
start "title=c:\Progra..." /command:....
```

and as the `start` command does not include a `/command` switch, it fails.

Comment: This works! Can you just please explain to me why `cmd /C ...` doesn't? From the description it seems like a more suitable command.

Comment: @Borek, `cmd /c` starts a new process `inside` of the current console. When the new `cmd`  ends then the previous instance will gain control again.

Comment: Understood, but the `TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:` takes about 100ms to execute (at least it does when typed manually in cmd.exe) so I don't quite understand why it's blocking the CLI if run from a batch file. Or the other way around - why is the CLI not blocked when this command is typed manually.. Strange, in my eyes.

Comment: @Borek, this is the standard behaviour. There are two kind of applications, console and gui. From command line, console applications block and gui don't block. From batch file both block. See `start /?`

Comment: Thanks, that's a very important difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use START to run the command.

```
start "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe" "/command:log"
```

Comment: Tried adding quotes around the whole thing but that doesn't help either. I don't think `start` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Put the arguments inside the quotations. I had edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry that just doesn't work - it opens a new console Windows which is not the same behavior as running the TortoseGitProc.exe with some parameters directly.

Comment: @Borek The START command do exactly what you asked. "Enables a user to start a separate window in Windows from the Windows command line." Maybe you should elaborate your question better.

Comment: I suggest you try to install TortoiseGit and try for yourself. I asked about running a TortoiseGitProc.exe command which opens a **GUI** window (not a new command window) and how to move the line that is working fine when I type it on command line to a batch file, where it seems to block the CLI. If anything, CMD command (http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) seems to be what I'm after but that doesn't work either for some reason.

Comment: @Borek No. You asked, literally: "How to run a command from a batch file and immediately return?" without any mention to GUI. In fact, there is no GUI in a batch. Good luck.